# How can I redirect http to https except a specific page, then redirect https to http for that same page?

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

I am redirecting all traffic from http to https except a specific page, but I would like on that specific page to have the the https redirect to http. How can I accomplish this. Below is what I have so far.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/page

Comment: For some reason it does the exact same thing. The https for that specific page still  is https, it never redirects to http. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I left what I had above in the httpd.conf file, then in the page directory I edited the .htaccess file and added the below code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```